# How to insert a SUM condition in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I want to select from the employees table only the departments where the total sum of the salaries is greater than 150000. Unfortunately I can't use "where sum(e.salary)>150000" because I get "ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here" error. Any idea how I could implement the filter?

```
SELECT e.department_id, sum(e.salary) summ
FROM employees e
//where sum(e.salary)>150000
group by e.department_id
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, move your logic in the `WHERE` clause to a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT e.department_id, SUM(e.salary) summ
FROM employees e
GROUP BY e.department_id
HAVING SUM(e.salary) > 150000;
```

The restrictions in the `WHERE` clause are applied to the table *before* aggregation in `GROUP BY` takes place.  The restrictions in the `HAVING` clause happen *after* `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Great, thnk you!